# Calendar/date picker Year error: Wrong number of arguments

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

This comes from a video tutorial. When I run this the first day of the month does not appear in the correct day of the week for that month.

I believe the issue is **Year** on this line in ShowDate():

```
last_date = VBA.DateSerial(Year(first_date), Month(first_date) + 1, 1) - 1
```

Similar tutorials follow the same structure, but I run into the same problem.

The error is

> Compile Error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

The full code.

```vb
Private Sub cmbMonth_Change()
If Me.cmbMonth.Value <> "" And Me.cmbYear.Value <> "" Then
    Call ShowDate
End If
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i As Integer

With Me.cmbMonth
    For i = 1 To 12
        .AddItem VBA.Format(VBA.DateSerial(2019, i, 1), "MMMM")
    Next i
    
    .Value = VBA.Format(VBA.Date, "MMMM")
End With

With Me.cmbYear
    For i = VBA.Year(Date) - 3 To VBA.Year(Date) + 4
        .AddItem i
    Next i
    
    .Value = VBA.Format(VBA.Date, "YYYY")
End With

End Sub


Sub ShowDate()

Dim first_date As Date
Dim last_date As Date

first_date = VBA.CDate("1-" & Me.cmbMonth.Value & "_" & Me.cmbYear.Value)
last_date = VBA.DateSerial(Year(first_date), Month(first_date) + 1, 1) - 1

Dim i As Integer
Dim btn As MSForms.CommandButton

''''to remove any caption from buttons
For i = 1 To 34
    Set btn = Me.Controls("CommandButton" & i)
    btn.Caption = ""
Next i

''''set first date of the month
For i = 1 To 7
    Set btn = Me.Controls("CommandButton" & i)
        If VBA.Weekday(first_date) = i Then
        btn.Caption = "1"
    End If
Next i

Dim btn1 As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim btn2 As MSForms.CommandButton

''''set all dates
For i = 1 To 33
    Set btn1 = Me.Controls("CommandButton" & i)
    Set btn2 = Me.Controls("CommandButton" & i + 1)
    
    If btn1.Caption <> "" Then
        If VBA.CInt(btn1.Caption) < VBA.Day(last_date) Then
            btn2.Caption = btn1.Caption + 1
        End If
    
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You should use DateSerial also for `first_date` (use the `Val`-function to convert from String to numbers), but if you insist using `CDate`, you should replace the underscore character in `& "_" &` with a hyphen.

Comment: Not committed to Cdate.  If I understood your suggestion correctly I made the following changes first_date = Val(VBA.DateSerial("1-" & Me.cmbMonth.Value & "-" & Me.cmbYear.Value))
last_date = Val(VBA.DateSerial(Year(first_date), Month(first_date) + 1, 1) - 1)  Still getting the same error though

Comment: `DateSerial(Val(Me.cmbYear.Value), Val(Me.cmbMonth.Value), 1)`

Comment: Unfortunately no change.  Do you by chance see any other errors in the code.  I believe I transcribed it exactly.  I've thought the issue might be with the form itself, but cannot find any errors there?

Comment: Which line throws the error? I just see that your Code is missing an `End If` before the `Next i`, but I don't see what could cause the "Wrong number of arguments" error.

Comment: I missed that End If.  The error occurs with Show_Date highlighted in yellow, and then in last_date definition the word Year is highlighted in blue.

Comment: I cannot repro this, can you add a breakpoint and then step through to find the exact line it breaks on.

Comment: Is it possible that you have defined an own item with name `year` that hides the VBA function? Click on Year and press Shift+F2. You can also try `VBA.year`.

Comment: Thanks FunThomas - that was the issue.  I added VBA. to both Year and Month, I also had to convert back to Cdate in the first_date definition to get the whole thing to function.  I don't see a spot where I check this as answered anymore(?)  but really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: You can't mark a comment on SO, only an answer. Comments are used to ask for details and the like. Still not convinced that you should use `CDate` as this implicitly converts a string to a date, and that can lead to a lot of confusion, depending on your regional settings an how *you* write a date vs how VBa thinks a date should look like, while `DateSerial` leaves no room for misinterpretation. Anyhow, that was not your question. I wrote a small answer that you can accept if you want

Comment: Yes I've given the check mark and I'll keep looking into best practices.  I'm very novice at this so I tend to work with what is available and try to adapt it to my needs.  I was aware of Cdate, but had not used DateSerial until this project.  Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that an object, variable or function with the name `Year` is defined in the code (not in the piece that is shown). This `Year` hides the regular VBA function `Year` and led to the compiler message.

If you want to force VBA to take the build-in function, you can access it via the Global VBA-object, just write `VBA.Year`.

However, it is best practise to avoid such ambiguities by avoiding such names.